# ¿Cómo sustituir position: fixed cuando se usa Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Por ahorro de tiempo usé flexbox. Le agrego la propiedad `position: fixed` a la barra de menú que se encuentra en el header, oero ocupa todo el espacio.

El logo y las opciones del menú van por separado porque quiero un diseño independiente para cada uno de ellos.
A la derecha tengo un logo y a la izquierda el menú, pero al hacer eso me abarca todo y se me descuadra.

¿Habrá alguna propiedad para sustituir el `fixed` ya que obviamente tengo el `display : flex;` y desconozco si estas propiedades entran en conflicto?

Mi código (también en [codepen](https://codepen.io/cacz/pen/ybbbNy)):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.cont-header {
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.ul-nav {
  list-style: none;
  ;
}

.li-nav {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.a-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor flex">
  <header class="cont-header flex">

    <div class="logo flex">
      <p>LOGO<span></span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="nav flex">
      <ul class="ul-nav flex">
        <li class="li-nav flex"><a class="a-nav" href="#">INICIO</a></li>
        <li class="li-nav flex"><a class="a-nav" href="#">EXPERIENCIA</a></li>
        <li class="li-nav flex"><a class="a-nav" href="#">PORTAFOLIO DE TRABAJO</a></li>
        <li class="li-nav flex"><a class="a-nav" href="#">REFERENCIAS</a></li>
        <li class="li-nav flex"><a class="a-nav" href="#">SOBRE MÍ</a></li>
        <li class="li-nav flex"><a class="a-nav" href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </header>
</div>
```

Necesito que el menú este visible al hacer scroll.

En el código css en las clases `.logo` y `.nav` es donde agrego la posición fixe y hacen que se rompa todo.

Comment: Puedes crear un caso simplificado en codepen o jsbin donde sea más fácil ver lo que estás haciendo. Eso aumenta la probabilidad de que alguien responda.

Comment: No es necesario usar un servicio externo. Edita tu pregunta y añade el código HTML, CSS y JavaScript (ícono </> en el editor).

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir una imagen del resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1):

Debes de aplicar `position: fixed` al contenedor de todo lo que quieres que quede fijo.

En tu código solo aplicas a partes como el `.nav` o `.logo` lo que hace que solo un `div` del header quede fija a la parte superior lo cual hace que el otro elemento `<div>` quedé encima.

Para que todo quede fijo arriba debes aplicar al `<header>` el `position: fixed`.

Revisa este [CodePen](https://codepen.io/victorcobden/pen/zwwwqo).

Comment: Cierto estaba complicando las cosas, en lugar de englobar todo le ponía la propiedad por separado haciendo que se rompiera el diseño. Gracias